# Multiplication with conditions

Tags: r, conditional-statements, multiplication

Suppose a data frame has the following structure:

```
x=c(1:18)
y=c(9:26)
k=c(NA)
id=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)
task=c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,2)
alts=c(2,3,1,2,3,1,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3)

data<-data.frame(id, task, alts, x, y, k)
```

Now I want to multiply x and y with different conditions, i.e.,

1. when id==i and task==j, prod(x);
2. when id==i and task!=j, prod(y);
3. when id==i, prod(y).

then k=prod(x)*prod(y)/(1-prod(y)). The first prod(y) in this equation comes from condition 2, and the second prod(y) comes from condition 3.

As an example, suppose I want to calculate k[1] (means id==1 and task==1), then k[1]=(x[1] * x[2]) * (y[3] * y[4] * y[5] * y[6] * y[7]) / (1 - y[1] * y[2] * ... * y[7]). k[2]=k[1] since k[2] in the data also represents conditions where id==1 and task==1.

the code I use is:

```
for (i in 1:3){ # for each individual

  for(j in 1:3){ # for each task of each individual

    data1=ddply(data, .(id, task), transform, k=prod(x[id==i & task==j])*prod(y[id==i & task!=j])/(1-prod(y[id==i])))
  }
}
```

I tried this code, but it did not work. Why the function **prod(x-condition 1)*prod(y-condition 2)/prod(y-condition 3)** doesn't work? Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Can you clarify what calculation you are trying to do?  Giving some pseudo code that describes your end result would be helpful.

If I'm interpreting your question correctly, your goal is to calculate: foreach id and task combination: calculate Prod(x for this id and task combination) * Prod(y for this id but not this task) / (1 - Prod(y for this id)).  

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes! you are correct! That's what I want to do. And this calculation ends with a column data such that each id and task combination has a unique calculated value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it may be clearest to do this in parts.  We can calculate each of your products separately and then combine them together.  This is not computationally optimal, but hopefully it's very readable.  I'll use your example data set as input:

```
x=c(1:18)
y=c(9:26)
k=c(NA)
id=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)
task=c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,2)
alts=c(2,3,1,2,3,1,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3)

data<-data.frame(id, task, alts, x, y, k)
```

The method I'm giving here is to calculate `prod(x by id and task)`, `prod(y by id and task)`, and `prod(y by id)` separately, then combine them at the end.

```
x.y.by.id.task <- aggregate(data.frame(x.id.task=data$x, y.id.task=data$y),
                            data[c("id", "task")], 
                            prod)
y.by.id      <- aggregate(data.frame(y.id=data$y), 
                          data["id"], 
                          prod)
```

Now `x.y.by.id.task` contains the products of x and y by id and task combinations, and `y.by.id` contains the product of y by id.  We can combine these into a single data frame and do the final computation with one vectorized operation.

```
id.task <- merge(x.y.by.id.task, y.by.id)

id.task$result <- 
  id.task$x.id.task * # prod(x by id by task)
  (id.task$y.id / id.task$y.id.task) / # prod(y by id and !task)
  (1 - id.task$y.id) # 1 - prod(y by id)
```

Now, in large data sets this approach is not computationally optimal, and depending on your problem setting you could run into numerical instability.  But this should be sufficient for many problem settings.  This solution is nice because R does the heavy lifting of finding id and task combinations and arranging the output for you.

Also, this only calculates values for id and task combinations that exist in your data set.  In your case, there are no id=3, task=3  combinations.  If you inspect the final id.task data.frame, you'll see that there are no rows where id=3 and task=3 (because there were no rows where this was true in data).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's try this, based on @leif's comment. I create a new element in your dataframe:

```
data$calc<- data$x*(data$id==ii & data$task==jj) * data$y*(data$id==ii & data$task!=jj)/ (1-(data$y*(data$id==ii)))
```

Now, for your sample data, this pretty much always comes out to zeros.  Perhaps you wanted to use the fact that `prod(x)` returns `1` for an empty vector? My calculation sets `x` or `y` to zero, so it would have to be modified to something like

```
data$calc<- max(1,data$x*(data$id==ii & data$task==jj)) * max(1,data$y*(data$id==ii & data$task!=jj))/ (1-(max(1,data$y*(data$id==ii))))
```

Which, of course, will be unhappy if you have any negative numbers in your dataset.

EDIT: you wrote that you want to take the product of all the x which meet the i,j criteria, so I believe this will work.  It's from memory since I left my 'scrapboard' at another location:

```
data$calc<- prod(data$x[data$id==ii & data$task==jj)]) * prod(data$y[(data$id==ii & data$task!=jj)])/ (1-prod(data$y[(data$id==ii)]) )
```

Comment: thank you so much for the effort. But it still doesn't work for me. I edited the original question and try to make it clearer. Can you see it again? Thx a million.